# Agrupar meses dependiendo del año

Tags: c#, visual-studio, charts

estoy practicando la generación de gráficos con chart de visual studio.

ya pude generar el grafico no encuentro la forma de poner el año como se visualiza en la primera imagen.

Como puedo agrupar y/o poner la cabecera  a la fila de los meses.(No se el nombre tecnico)

Si visualizan el código podrán ver que desde el mes de abril hasta diciembre es del año 2021 y de enero a marzo es del año del 2022

[image: Imagen1]

hasta el momento logre generar un ejemplo pero no logro poner los años
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi código

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string series = "TestData";
        string series2 = "Test";
        
        chart.Series.Clear();

        
        chart.Series.Add(series);
        chart.Series.Add(series2);
        chart.Series[series].XValueType = ChartValueType.String;
        chart.Series[series].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
        chart.Series[series].BorderWidth = 4;
        
        chart.Series[series].Points.AddXY(new DateTime(2021, 4, 1), 72.05);
        chart.Series[series].Points.AddXY(new DateTime(2021, 5, 1), 60);
        chart.Series[series].Points.AddXY(new DateTime(2021, 6, 1), 50);
        chart.Series[series].Points.AddXY(new DateTime(2021, 7, 1), 25);
        chart.Series[series].Points.AddXY(new DateTime(2021, 8, 1), 10);
        chart.Series[series].Points.AddXY(new DateTime(2021, 9, 1), 40);
        chart.Series[series].Points.AddXY(new DateTime(2021, 10, 1), 130);
        chart.Series[series].Points.AddXY(new DateTime(2021, 11, 1), 200.05);
        chart.Series[series].Points.AddXY(new DateTime(2021, 12, 1), 10.05);
        chart.Series[series].Points.AddXY(new DateTime(2022, 1, 2), 40);
        chart.Series[series].Points.AddXY(new DateTime(2022, 2, 2), 20);
        chart.Series[series].Points.AddXY(new DateTime(2022, 3, 2), 30);

        chart.Series[series2].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
        chart.Series[series2].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
        chart.Series[series2].BorderWidth = 4;
        
        chart.Series[series2].Points.AddXY(new DateTime(2021, 4, 1), 102.05);
        chart.Series[series2].Points.AddXY(new DateTime(2021, 5, 1), 20);
        chart.Series[series2].Points.AddXY(new DateTime(2021, 6, 1), 40);
        chart.Series[series2].Points.AddXY(new DateTime(2021, 7, 1), 35);
        chart.Series[series2].Points.AddXY(new DateTime(2021, 8, 1), 200);
        chart.Series[series2].Points.AddXY(new DateTime(2021, 9, 1), 140);
        chart.Series[series2].Points.AddXY(new DateTime(2021, 10, 1), 180);
        chart.Series[series2].Points.AddXY(new DateTime(2021, 11, 1), 100.05);
        chart.Series[series2].Points.AddXY(new DateTime(2021, 12, 1), 80.05);
        chart.Series[series2].Points.AddXY(new DateTime(2022, 1, 2), 20);
        chart.Series[series2].Points.AddXY(new DateTime(2022, 2, 2), 10);
        chart.Series[series2].Points.AddXY(new DateTime(2022, 3, 2), 50);

        
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.Gray;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dash;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.Gray;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dash;

        
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "MMM";
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Months;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalOffsetType = DateTimeIntervalType.Years;
       
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Al final solo era registrar un CustomLabels con sus dimensiones

```
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(new DateTime(2021, 4, 1).ToOADate(), new DateTime(2021, 12,1).ToOADate(), "2021", 1, LabelMarkStyle.LineSideMark);
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(new DateTime(2022, 1, 2).ToOADate(), new DateTime(2022, 3, 2).ToOADate(), "2022", 1, LabelMarkStyle.LineSideMark);
```